# "prototype" property not for all way of object creation

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was trying to create object different way and trying to observe prototype property of the object created in each way.

```
var a = {a: 1}; 
//The prototype chain as mentioned in [here][1]
// a ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

Now, i have observed that a.prototype is undefined. 
Question1:If it is undefined then how the prototype chain is formed? a.hasOwnProperty exist because of prototype chain.

Now if i say:

```
var myFunc = function(){};
// Prototype chain: myFunc ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype ---> null
```

for this way of creation, myFunc.prototype exist.

Question2: Why this difference exist?

Comment: `prototype` is a special property that only functions have.

Comment: Constructor functions have prototype, you can use Object.create to create an (empty or second argument) object with the passed object (first argument) as the first prototype used to look up the prototype chain. More on how this works here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prototype` attribute isn't the object's prototype. That's (usually) the `__proto__` attribute, although I don't think any version of the ECMAScript standard requires that attribute. The `prototype` attribute of a function `Foo` is the object that will be used as the prototype for an object generated by `new Foo()`.

Comment: While `.__proto__` is deprecated in most browsers, I believe that ES6 is adding full support for the property, as a magical (mutable) getter/setter.